# Java multithreading error

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

Can anyone explain to me why does this program gives an error when I try to use `while` instead of `if` statement inside `run()` method?

**Code not working**:

```
public class threadHello implements Runnable {
    public static int counter = 0;
    Thread t;

    void newThread() {

        t = new Thread(this, "Thread: " + Integer.toString(counter));
        helloWord();
        counter++;
        t.start();

    }

    void helloWord() {
        System.out.println(t.getName() + ": Hello from Thread: " + counter);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (counter < 51)
            newThread();

    }
}
```

**Code that works**:

```
public class threadHello implements Runnable {
    public static int counter = 0;
    Thread t;

    void newThread() {

        t = new Thread(this, "Thread: " + Integer.toString(counter));
        helloWord();
        counter++;
        t.start();

    }

    void helloWord() {
        System.out.println(t.getName() + ": Hello from Thread: " + counter);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (counter < 51)
            newThread();
    }
}
```

And when I put the same condition inside my `newThread()` method program works with both `if` and `while` solutions. I would like to understand why?

Comment: What's the error that you get with while?

Comment: Here it is: 
Exception in thread "Thread: 7" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
 at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:708)
 at reversehello.threadHello.newThread(threadHello.java:13)
 at reversehello.threadHello.run(threadHello.java:23)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: That's because you are restarting the same thread again and again in while loop, while with if you are just starting the thread once. You cannot start the same thread multiple times. See the runnable instance that you are passing is the same accross multiple thread instance that you are trying to create.

Comment: @SMA I don't think passing the same runnable instance to multiple threads is the issue here. I think that's perfectly fine. For me the problem is a race condition in the assignment of the ``t`` instance field since all loop iterations reuse that same field, then two iterations may end up trying to start the same thread due to race conditions. As a matter of fact if we synchronize the ``newThread`` method the problem is gone, which kind of proves this theory. Although, bottom line, you're right, this is about starting the same thread again, just not for the reasons implied as far as I can tell.